# Round Down and Round Up float to negative decimals point in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for something to round up and round down at 1,2, and -1 decimal points in python, I have written some logic through it I am able to get the right values for +ve points but still looking round down -ve values.

my code is as -:

```
import decimal

outcome = '2156.24611496733'
rounding="Alwayes Down" 
decimal_place = -1

#   for positive values
if rounding == "Alwayes Up":
    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_UP

elif rounding == "Alwayes Down":
    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_DOWN

#   for negative values
if rounding == "Alwayes Down":
    print(round(float(outcome), decimal_place))

rounding_string = "1." + "0"*int(decimal_place)
decimal_outcome = decimal.Decimal(str(outcome)).quantize(decimal.Decimal(rounding_string))

print(decimal_outcome)
```

Table value is like - [image]

I am expecting values like

[image]

Comment: Please, share your DataFrame https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I have added a data frame, I am looking for Always Down -1 point.

Comment: I don't see any data, just screenshots

Comment: There is no rounding down function in python only truncating, like this :  x = 622222.5454//1; print(x)

Comment: ok, I am looking to round Down at -1 position. and there are round-down options after setting context i.e working fine for me. https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/programming/python-rounding-numbers

Comment: How about 622222.5454//10*10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete solution that meets my matrix.

```
import decimal

outcome = '622222.545454545'
rounding="Alwayes Up" 
decimal_place = -1

#   for positive values
if rounding == "Alwayes Up":
    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_UP

elif rounding == "Alwayes Down":
    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_DOWN
    
rounding_string = "1." + "0"*int(decimal_place)
decimal_outcome = decimal.Decimal(str(outcome)).quantize(decimal.Decimal(rounding_string))

print(decimal_outcome)

# for negative values
if rounding == "Alwayes Up":
    print(round(float(outcome), decimal_place))

elif rounding == "Alwayes Up":
    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_UP
    rounding_string = "1." + "0"*int(decimal_place)
    decimal_outcome = decimal.Decimal(str(outcome)).quantize(decimal.Decimal(rounding_string))
    print(float(decimal_outcome))
```